# access child composition container in mef

Tags: mef

Given a composition container that holds a nested composition container, how do I access the nested container?

Answer (score 1):

By default you cannot directly access the nested containers you passed to a container. However you could look at the Providers property which will list all the ExportProviders that are currently being used by a given CompositionContainer (CompositionContainer is just a special ExportProvider) and find the ones that are CompositionContainers.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't understand. Suppose I've created a parent container with a child composition container. If I do int num = parentCompostionContainer.Providers.Count; num will be zero.